# Unlock files and folders

Tags: command-line

How do I unlock files and folders so I can delete them?  I have Bakno Pinball version 9.0.0.0 and want to delete it so I can load and run the newer version.
The files are locked and I cannot unlock them.

I tried `chown` and that is not working.

Comment: check the permissions?

Comment: How did you install it and where is it located?

Comment: I installed it from the Ubuntu software center.  It is located in the OPT folder.

Comment: Just use the software center to uninstall it!  Always use the same [uninstall method as the installation method](http://askubuntu.com/a/575161/344926) or you'll break your system!

Answer (score 0):

To trash files or directories :: Open the terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

`cd` into the directory which contains your file and :

```
sudo gvfs-trash /filename/
```

Hope this'll help.